# Sobel operator for point clouds

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to wrap my head around applying Sobel operator to the pointcloud data.

If the 2D case of the Sobel operator can be written as:

```
sobel_x = np.array([[-1, 0, 1],
                    [-2, 0, 2],
                    [-1, 0, 1]])

sobel_y = np.array([[-1, -2, -1], 
                    [ 0,  0, 0], 
                    [ 1,  2, 1]])

filtered_image_x = cv2.filter2D(grayscale, -1, sobel_x)
filtered_image_y = cv2.filter2D(grayscale, -1, sobel_y)

gradient_magnitude = np.sqrt(np.square(filtered_image_x) + np.square(filtered_image_y))
gradient_magnitude = gradient_magnitude.astype(np.float)
gradient_magnitude *= 255.0 / gradient_magnitude.max()
```

According to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator#Extension_to_other_dimensions), what filters `h'(x)h(y)h(z)` correspond to? Does it mean that `h'(x)=[1,0,-1]` and `h(x)=[1,2,1]`?

There is the same question asked here [implement 3d sobel operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330746/implement-3d-sobel-operator), but I do not understand what individual filters are for each dimension and how to apply those ?1D? filters to each dimension

Comment: What does your pointcloud look like?

Comment: @CrisLuengo At the moment I am just testing with the `def get_random_list(a_range, size): return [random.random() * a_range for _ in range(0, size)] xs = get_random_list(20, 100) ys = get_random_list(20, 100) zs = get_random_list(20, 100) img = np.column_stack((xs, ys, zs))` since the actual point cloud looks similar

Comment: What do you expect the gradient in that data to look like? You have a uniform distribution of points in the volume.

Comment: Maybe you’re interpreting the data as a function R^2 -> R, and are looking for a 2D gradient?

Comment: @CrisLuengo That is a good point that the random data may have a certain distribution.. My aim is to use the Sobel operator in order to identify edges for the downstream task. My data for the most part constists of buildings and roads, so horizontal or vertical planes. I should be looking into patches whos normal vectors have the same orientation, but I want to start with simpler task of detecting edges and corners

Comment: @CrisLuengo or should I be looking into 3D convolution (`https://miro.medium.com/max/2880/1*z5wfLwBCEgAPTI_U1mSaVA.png`) but then what the 3D sobel operator would look like?

Comment: You’re talking about edges and corners of the surface where the dots are distributed on? That means an edge is a line that has points on one side but not the other. I don’t see how Sobel can help you there. You probably need to fit planes to your data, then analyze those.

Comment: @CrisLuengo in that case one of the approaches could be to sample randomly points from the 3D space, collect N neighbours and apply something like `https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/computations/fitting/skspatial.objects.Plane.best_fit.html#skspatial.objects.Plane.best_fit` to get the plane of the neighbourhood?